# Why are certain URLs forbidden to use?

Tags: support

I tried to use this URL today in a post as a reference but the editor did not want to let me:

china highlights.com (remove space to make link work)

said explicitly that chinahighlights.com is not allowed. I was trying to support my answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16037/flag-raising-ceremony-in-beijing). Interestingly, here it is allowed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We've had several (I know as I had to deal with them) spammers inserting China Highlights as an address.  We suspended the users, warned them with email, and as soon as they were unsuspended they continued to include it in useless answers and links.

As a result, I went with my evidence to the community team, as I can't personally as a moderator block addresses, and they deemed it necessary and appropriate to block the site from future answers, and I've destroyed the associated user accounts that were perpertrating this.

I too found it a shame, as one of my early answers on China included a link to it (perhaps how they found traffic coming from this site).  I've since removed it, and once you've seen my answer to this, I'd suggest doing the same, unfortunately :(

Hope that answers your question!